# Best practices for versioning an XCode project for open source?

Tags: github, version-control-systems

I'm preparing to open source an XCode project I've been working on privately, on Github.

I am planning on using Github's `release` feature and and tag the initial release as 0.1.0. This much I know.

But I have one question: What's the best practice for the version number and build id of the XCode project itself going forward?

1. Do I need to update the version/build-id every time raise a version on Github?
2. Should these numbers be synchronized?

Comment: What? Why did this get a down vote without explanation? That's just sad :( I think this is a good question, and definitely deserves an up vote around here.

Comment: This is strictly an opinion based question, though a large consensus would say to just use semver, and I'd agree! But what do you mean by "raise a version on Github"??

Comment: @curiousdannii you can specify version and build id on XCode projects. I was wondering if this should be in sync with the version I use on Github. The former is for shipping a product. You are required to raise versions everytime you re-submit to the appstore. On the other hand, the latter is more for milestone purpose. I wasn't sure what the best practice was for dealing with both.